# Cube only displays if I call glPopMatrix after glEnd (not the other way around)

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I am encountering a very weird issue in OpenGl. The following code produces a yellow cube as expected

```
glPushMatrix();
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, (GLfloat[]){ 1, 1, 0, 1 });
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glutSolidCube(1);
glPopMatrix();
glEnd();
```

However when I put glpopMatrix() after glEnd(), I just get a black screen without a cube.

```
glPushMatrix();
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, (GLfloat[]){ 1, 1, 0, 1 });
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glutSolidCube(1);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

To me the second approach makes more sense, (push, begin, end then pop) and I really have no idea why it does not work. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Since the second example should be the correct one, I strongly suspect that whatever is wrong with your code is outside the code that you posted. Are you in fact altering the matrix between `PushMatrix` and `PopMatrix`? If so, it's *probably* (just guessing, though) that the new matrix that you're creating is wrong, while the one prior to that is correct, and since you pop the previous one back before `glEnd`, it is actually the one that gets used for transforming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the placement of the `glPopMatrix()` call. The problem is with `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`. Remove them, `glutSolidCube()` does that already.

If you're using FreeGLUT then `glutSolidCube()` won't even be using `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`, and will be using vertex arrays under the hood. So to put it simply, you're probably just confusing your driver and that's why you're getting the weird result.